# Python: Taking input from a file and storing it as an int data type

Tags: python-3.x, input, file-handling

I have an input file 'input.dat':

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

I store the data in a 2D array and try to process as in the given code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataFile = open("/Users/atulyaratanjha/Documents/Python/P11.dat")
    arr = []
    for line in dataFile:
        arr.append(line.split())
    maxMult = 0
    for i in range(16):
        for j in range(20):
            mult = arr[i][j] * arr[i+1][j] * arr[i+2][j] * arr[i+3][j]
            maxMult = max(maxMult, mult)
    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(16):
            mult = arr[i][j] * arr[i][j+1] * arr[i][j+2] * arr[i][j+3]
            maxMult = max(maxMult, mult)
    for i in range(16):
        for j in range(16):
            mult = arr[i][j] * arr[i+1][j+1] * arr[i+2][j+2] * arr[i+2][j+3]
            maxMult = max(maxMult, mult)
    print(maxMult)
```

It gives this Error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I know that I can change the data into 'int' from 'str' by running a for loop, but is there any way to store the data as 'int' at the input stage?

Comment: Change the `arr.append(line.split())` to `arr.append(list(map(int, line.split())))` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !!!

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Answer (score 0):

Andrej Kesely explains you might
change the

```
arr.append(line.split())
```

to

```
arr.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
```

and it should work.

Comment: If you are copying someone's comment into an answer, you should conventionally mark it as Community Wiki. The term is kind of crazy (there is no wiki here) but it basically means you abstain from the reputation earnings.